# running the example wordcount " Exception in thread "main"

Tags: hadoop, program-entry-point

I tried to run the example wordcount programm, my hdfs file saved in /input, and the output dir is /output, here is the command i executed:

```
[hadoop-2.2.0]$ bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/sources/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0-sources.jar org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount /input /output
```

but I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:205
```

Answer (score 0):

try hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar

```
bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar wordcount /input /output
```

if you do want to use the source jar, you could run below first:

```
unset HADOOP_CLASSPATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you are using source file. You would rather execute $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/sources/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar 
instead. Maybe it will help.